# MVC4 Is my Connection String to SQL Server 2014 correct

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, database-connection, connection-string

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for Web and I'm coding a MVC application. By default it uses a localDB but I want it on a SQL Server. I've installed SQL Server 2014 and my servername is C0208\SQLEXPRESS.

C0208 is my computer name

Named Instance: SQLEXPRESS

InstanceID: SQLEXPRESS

This is my connectionstring to the localdb

```
<add name="IssueContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I tried using this connection string and I don't know if it's correct or not

```
<add name="IssueContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=C0208\SQLEXPRESS;User Id=C0208;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Comment: I can go onto the index page but it won't let me use the other tabs So? I get this error `Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.`

Comment: @David I've had 2 recurring errors. The one i mentioned above and another about not being able to find the connection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more of an Entity Framework issue rather than the SQL connection string. Just check if you have updated the connection string everywhere. (**app.config**).
To Enable data migration you will have to run the following command in the **Package Manager Console**.

```
enable-migrations
```

if it gives an error than try the following command first

```
add-migration projectName
```

For more details check [this link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)